# MDX Excel Pivot formula

Tags: excel, pivot, mdx

Would appreciate any help with this, I’m struggling with the MDX  trying to calculate BMI ( Body Mass Index = Weight / Height Squared ), as a Calculated Member in PivotTable Tools -> Analyze -> OLAP Tools -> MDX Calculated Member.

I believe I need an IF, as Height might be 0 in some cases, and hence /DIV0 issues.

IF [Height] IS > 0 THEN ( [Weight] / ( [Height] * [Height] ) ELSE 0 END IF

Thanks in advance for any help.

Thanks
Gav

Comment: do you need a measure creating `mdx`? I can see one answer posted but it is not mdx

Answer (score 0):

please try the below in the calculated field:

```
=IF(Height> 0,Weight/(Height *Height ),0)
```

If this is not what you are looking for please let me know :)

Comment: 'IF' does not exist in `MDX` - you need to use `IIF`  - also you need to wrap everything up with an aggregate function - so maybe try wrapping it in `SUM(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need `mdx` then the operator `if` does not exist - you should use `iif`:

```
IIF(
  [Measures].[Height] = 0
 ,NULL
 ,DIVIDE(
     [Measures].[Weight]
   , ( [Measures].[Height] * [Measures].[Height] )
 )
)
```

As you are creating a measure I think this needs to be wrapped in an Aggregate function:

```
SUM(
IIF(
  [Measures].[Height] = 0
 ,NULL
 ,DIVIDE(
     [Measures].[Weight]
   , ( [Measures].[Height] * [Measures].[Height] )
 )
 )
)
```